# Why is Python3 throwing an error when calling an external command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, fail2ban

I am using Fail2Ban to monitor various logs. I am using the AWS ACL Fail2Ban from Anthony Martin found at https://github.com/anthonymartin/aws-acl-fail2ban.

When the action calls an external script the following error is thrown:

```
    2018-04-10 23:25:32,426 fail2ban.action [5638]: DEBUG   /opt/AWS_ACL_Fail2Ban/aws-acl-fail2ban -i acl-e05a8898 -b 50.97.23.5 -- stderr: b'Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from awscli.formatter import get_formatter
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 19, in <module>
    from awscli.table import MultiTable, Styler, ColorizedStyler
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/table.py", line 19, in <module>
    from awscli.compat import six
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/compat.py", line 69, in <module>
    binary_stdin = sys.stdin.buffer
    AttributeError: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'buffer\'
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from awscli.formatter import get_formatter
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 19, in <module>
    from awscli.table import MultiTable, Styler, ColorizedStyler
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/table.py", line 19, in <module>
    from awscli.compat import six
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/compat.py", line 69, in <module>
    binary_stdin = sys.stdin.buffer
    AttributeError: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'buffer\'
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from awscli.formatter import get_formatter
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 19, in <module>
    from awscli.table import MultiTable, Styler, ColorizedStyler
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/table.py", line 19, in <module>
    from awscli.compat import six
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/compat.py", line 69, in <module>
    binary_stdin = sys.stdin.buffer
    AttributeError: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'buffer\'
    `'
2018-04-10 23:25:32,426 fail2ban.action [5638]: DEBUG   /opt/AWS_ACL_Fail2Ban/aws-acl-fail2ban -i acl-e05a8898 -b 50.97.23.5 -- returned successfully
```

Here is the action file:

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# IMPORTANT: Update actionban and actionunban with path to
# Author: Anthony Martin
#
#

[Definition]

# Option:  actionban
# Notes.:  command executed when banning an IP. Take care that the
#          command is executed with Fail2Ban user rights.
# Tags:    See jail.conf(5) man page
# Values:  CMD
#
actionban = /opt/AWS_ACL_Fail2Ban/aws-acl-fail2ban -i acl-e05a8898 -b <ip>

# Option:  actionunban
# Notes.:  command executed when unbanning an IP. Take care that the
#          command is executed with Fail2Ban user rights.
# Tags:    See jail.conf(5) man page
# Values:  CMD
#
actionunban = /opt/AWS_ACL_Fail2Ban/aws-acl-fail2ban -i acl-e05a8898 -u <ip>

actionstart =
actioncheck =
actionstop =
```

Server Details:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 2.7.12
Python 3.5.2
```

When I execute the command `/opt/AWS_ACL_Fail2Ban/aws-acl-fail2ban -i acl-e05a8898 -u 50.97.23.5` from the command line it works as expected. Only when it is called by Fail2Ban do I get the Python error.

Can someone please enlighten me as to how I should be entering the command in the action file?

Thank you.

Comment: What Python is it using? It is using Python 2 as its `sys.stdin` does not have a `buffer` property. You should look at what the files `#!` line is and if you can't correct that run the program with `python3` in front of it.

Comment: The error messages reference Python 3.

Comment: This probably explains why it happens: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2518